# Blender move single UV point

Tags: textures, models, blender, art, uv-mapping

Texturing in Blender and when I am moving UVs around in the UV/Image Editor I'm finding that I can't move a single UV point without moving all other UVs that are connected to the vertex.

This seems odd to me as the UV unwrap should be completely distinct from the mesh. Is there some odd setting that I don't realise I have turned on?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem, and it's costing me hours. Thanks for any help!

Comment: No solution unfortunately. I ended up slicing up the entire model up into very distinct blocks e.g. top of wing, bottom of wing, etc. then taking each block and unwrapping it and moving it in to position.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blender and should be asked on the Blender stack exchange.